# Iterate through series of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to define a series of dictionaries and then iterate through them below. I've tried putting the dictionary names into a list to iterate over, but that then throws up an error that a string does not have `.keys()` method. I'm presuming that is because Python thinks the values in the list are just strings and not meant to represent the dictionaries above.

I'm not sure how else I could code this though. The code is here:

```
prem_year_map = {
    2011: 2935,
    2012: 3389,
    2013: 3853,
    2014: 4311, 
}
year_tournament_map = {
    2013: 8273,
    2012: 6978,
    2011: 5861,
    2010: 4940,
}

tournament_list = [prem_year_map, year_tournament_map]

for x in tournament_list:
    years = sorted(tournament_list.keys())
    print years
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative method?

Thanks

Comment: `sorted(x.keys())` instead of `sorted(tournament_list.keys())`?

Comment: What's the output you're expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm presuming that is because Python thinks the values in the list are just strings and not meant to represent the dictionaries above.

This is not right. A list in Python can contain any type of reference.

You simply need to use the `object.keys()` instead of `tournament_list.keys()` (the latter you are asking for keys of the list, which do not exist - the dictionaries have the keys)

```
for x in tournament_list:
    years = sorted(x.keys())
    print years
```

As pointed out by @JonClements you can also used `sorted(x)` which returns a list (and is a bit more efficient in Python 2.x). Note that it can't return a dictionary since the standard dictionary cannot preserve an order.

Comment: The use of `.keys` here is totally redundant

Comment: You are right. I do like adding `.keys()`, since it makes the intent much clearer. In ruby for example, sorting a hash/dictionary returns a hash/dictionary.

Comment: Indeed but in Python 2.x it returns a list which is un-necessary and not efficient - since a `dict`'s `__iter__` is its keys: `sorted(x)` does the job on both 2.x and 3.x...

Answer (score 2):

To iterate dictionary key and value you need use different iterator.

```
for key, value in {}.iteritems():
  print key, value
```

The best choice is standard [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

```
for key, value in itertools.chain(dict1.iteritems(), dict2.iteritems())
  print key, value
```

You can also do list of iterators and iterate them.

```
iterators = []
iterators.append(oneDict.iteritems())

for iterator in iterators:
 for item in iterator:
   yield item # (key, value)
```

Choose what is the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
for x in tournament_list:
    years = sorted(x.keys())
    print years
```

Otherwise you are trying to get the `keys` from the list of dictionaries (which of course make no sense).

Comment: The use of `.keys` here is totally redundant